# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list (Python)

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `Ii0` containing numpy arrays with different shapes. I want to reorganize these arrays based on increasing `j`. But I get an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
Ii0 = [np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 4],[4,3]]),
       np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 5],[4,3],[3,4]])]

order = [k[:,1].argsort() for k in Ii0]
print(order)
Ii01 =Ii0[order]
print("Ii01 =",[Ii01])
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    Ii01 =Ii0[order]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[4,3],[2, 4]]),
 array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[4,3],[3,4],[2, 5]])]
```

Comment: Review your basic Python tutorial or book.  Python lists can only be index with scalars or slices.  The error makes this clear.  `I10` is a list - you said so yourself.  If you want to reorder the arrays in the list, you have do so to each array individually.  I don't think a list comprehension helps you here.  Just iterate on the list, and do the sort for each array.  You don't need to collect the `order` as list or arrays - get it and use it.

Comment: I want to have the ```order``` since I will use this to reorder another list.

Comment: `order` is a list of arrays. `I10` is a list of arrays.  What's wrong with the obvious iterative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope it'll helps you

```
import numpy as np
Ii0 = [np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 4],[4,3]]),
       np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 5],[4,3],[3,4]])]

Ii01 = [i[i[:,1].argsort()] for i in Ii0]
print("Ii01 =",Ii01)

>> Ii01 = [array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[4, 3],[2, 4]]), array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[4, 3],[3, 4],[2, 5]])]
```

Comment: Please have a look at the expected output.

Comment: there you go , edited

Comment: It works but is it possible to define ```order``` as I mention in the post? I want to use ```order``` to reorder another list containing numpy arrays.

Comment: in this case i  just used your last output variable name , you can change your variable name as which you want to be